# yeoman build process

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

So I'm currently using Yeoman which I very much love. I have a task to do which is grab my angular app and make it serverless. Basically this means grabbing all of the templates and inserting them into the index.html file with

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dir to template"> ..template html goes here </script>
```

Now yeoman has its own gruntfile and I'm totally a newb to Grunt so I'm wondering if 
a) This should be a task handled by grunt ?

b) Should I tweak the existing grunt file or create a new one?
c) Any good ideas of where I can find documentation on how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're working on making Yeoman more easily customizable, but in the meantime you can override the `build` task by adding this in your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.renameTask('build', 'oldbuild');
grunt.registerTask('build', 'your-task oldbuild');
```

This will let you add whatever task you want to the build process.

---

If you want to customize further you could override `build` instead and just piece together what you want from the tasks yeoman provides: `usemin-handler rjs concat css min img rev usemin manifest html`.

Example:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'your-task rjs concat css whatever-you-want');
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to customize the yeoman build process. But you can use this **workaround**. Copy the following code to your own Gruntfile:

```
// Clobber the original targets
var targets = {
    // Add as many custom targets as you want, using custom modules, etc.

    // Keep the existing targets
    default   : '               rjs concat css min img rev usemin manifest',
    usemin    : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css img rev usemin manifest',
    text      : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css min     rev usemin manifest',
    buildkit  : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css min img rev usemin manifest html:buildkit',
    basics    : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css min img rev usemin manifest html:basics',
    minify    : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css min img rev usemin manifest html:compress',
    test      : 'usemin-handler rjs concat css img rev usemin manifest',

    yourbuild : 'intro clean mkdirs rjs'
};

// If we clobber targets, we have to rebuild targetList, the below is copy paster from Yeoman.js
var targetList = grunt.log.wordlist(Object.keys(targets));

// We also have to rebuild the build task with the new targetList
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Run a predefined target - build:<target> \n' + targetList,  function(target) {
    var valid = Object.keys(targets);
    target = target || 'usemin';

    if ( valid.indexOf( target ) === -1 ) {
        grunt.log
        .error('Not a valid target')
        .error(grunt.helper('invalid targets', targets));
        return false;
    }

    var tasks = ['intro', 'clean coffee compass mkdirs', targets[target], 'copy time'].join(' ');

    // Now overwrite the task for our costume build
    if( target === 'yourbuild') {
        tasks = targets[target];
    }

    // Conditionally remove compass / manifest task if either compass or
    // phantomjs binary is missing. Done only for `test` target (specifically
    // used for our `npm test`). For each, output warning infos.
    if( target === 'test' ) {
        tasks = grunt.helper( 'build:skip', tasks, 'compass' );
        tasks = grunt.helper( 'build:skip', tasks, 'phantomjs', 'manifest' );
    }

    grunt.log.subhead('Running ' + target + ' target')
    .writeln('  - ' + grunt.log.wordlist(tasks.split(' '), { separator: ' ' }));

    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Now you can change the following line to customize your own build process:

```
yourbuild : 'intro clean mkdirs rjs'
```

But please remember, that this code is **copied from the yeoman source** and if it is updated you must do same by yourself.

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Thank you very much netzzwerg, super helpful.

Comment: Duplicating internal code is not the way to do it and will definitely break your code some time in the future. I've updated my answer to reflect another way you could achieve the same.